# /usr/bin/safaridriver for Safari 10.1.2 (12603.3.8) on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 prompts for password on every invocation; even in same shell session

Tags: macos, selenium, safaridriver

This:

```
$ /usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0
Password:
<ctrl+c>
$ /usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0
Password:
```

Ideally I'd love to never authenticate when starting safaridriver, but this appears to be a requirement now-- however, I have a test-runner which makes multiple invocations (one per test) of the safaridriver which means I have to type a password for *every* test, which is terrible.

This is a new problem for me.  Seems to have cropped up sometime in the past 2 weeks.  Also, prior to this, I never had to authenticate even once before to run tests with safaridriver.

Is there *any* way to disable the authentication requirement?

Comment: Can you run `sudo /usr/bin/safaridriver` once and see if that fixes the issue. It required to be done only once, not sure why you need to enter password again and again

Answer (score 0):

Please ask your system administrator to add /usr/bin/safaridriver command for the user in the sudoers file.